# Python Redirect traffic to url

Tags: python, packets

I am currently learning networking in python. I am 1 day in so don't be very strict with me. I have built a MITM (for testing purposes obviously), and I have all traffic from my phone pass through my main machine and be forwarded to router. I can see all the requests with wireshark , but how do I redirect the http traffic to a specific url if I know the IP and MAC of the device ? I imagine , that since the traffic is going through my machine , I can somehow capture the packet before it gets back (by tricking the router as well) and modify it. Or maybe even capture the request and change it before it is even routed from my machine. The thing is , I have no idea how to do that. Any suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. Do you want to write an HTTP proxy that alters the transmitted data, or do you want to rewrite IP packets on the wire?

Comment: It looks like you want to build a `man in the middle` script. You can start searching in google for some ideas.

Comment: I want to write something that will make any requests on my phone be redirected to a specific URL. Like if for example , I use my phone to try and access a website , my computer (which is monitoring all the traffic of my phone) will receive the HTTP request , alter it , and thus , when the response gets back to my phone , it will be redirected to another unrelated address. I am new to this , so I may be seeing this in the wrong way.

Comment: I have already built an MITM. How do I use it to redirect traffic ?